# no redirect rule for mobile redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I use .htaccess code for mobile redirects:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|epoc|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mmp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|wap|wap1|wap2|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some site [R=302,L]
```

However, I want some mobile IPs/mobile User Agents to be excluded from the above redirection, not to be denied. I want they to see the desktop site.
How I can do this with .htaccess code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `RewriteCond` for exclusion:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(11\.22\.33\.44|55\.66\.77\.88)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(excluded-agent1|excluded-agent2|excluded-agent3)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|iphone|ipod|ipad|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|epoc|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|iris|kindle|sgh|brew|htc|j2me|lg|midp|mmp|mot|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|operamini|palm|plucker|pocket|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|smartphone|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|wap|wap1|wap2|webos|windowsce|xda|xiino) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /desktop-site [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, anubhava! No, "some site" in my code is mobile site, no desktop. I want all user agents in my code to be redirected to my mobile - "some site", excluded mobile agents to pass the code and to view my desktop site. How this can be impelement with IP addresses?

Comment: Sorry I am enable to understand your comment. This answer is for this requirement `I want some mobile IPs/mobile User Agents to be excluded`. If you want to block certain IPs then use `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}` condition.

Comment: Sorry, anubhava!
I don`t want to block some mobile user agents or IPs, I want to exclude them from the mobile redirection, i.e. they must to see the site as desktop users, not mobile. What condition I must to use for such IPs?

Comment: Anubhava, I tried your code, but is not working. Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: You need to define your requirement clearly. You wrote `I want some mobile IPs/mobile User Agents to be excluded` and first condition in my code exactly does that `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(excluded-agent1|excluded-agent2|excluded-agent3)` Now tell me for which IP/agent it didn't work?

Comment: Can`t tell you, cos you can`t check it.
What means "RewriteRule ^ /desktop-site [R=302,L]" in your code? There must be mobile site, where I want to redirect no-excluded user agents.

Comment: lol :) I am not going to run it. I wanted to know for which user agent this exclusion rule isn't working. I can only assist based on the facts provided. Unless you update your question with your full .htaccess and tell me for which agent it didn't work there is nothing much I can do.

Comment: Very sorry, anubhava, works perfectly! You was right, the name of the user agent, which I use, was wrong. Great thanks for the help!
How can I exclude and IPs from this redirection?

Comment: Great to know it worked. See updated code on how to exclude IPs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, anubhava! This is great help for me!

Comment: Anubhava, I need help to exclude and some domain. Is this a correct line to do this for the above code:
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
Thank you!

Comment: `REMOTE_HOST` is client's hostname. If you want to exclude some server domain then use `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Comment: Thank you, anubhava, again, for your correct and helpful answer!